# Is the wave lagging or ahead?

Tags: waves

[image]

Why do we say, the red wave is ahead of the green wave, and the green wave is lagging behind the red wave. From my understanding, the displacement on the graph only refers to the amplitude of the way. So how can we use a displacmeent/time graph and state the green wave is lagging behind the red one?

Here's the explanation in the textbook.

> The red wave is leading the green wave. We can see this by comparing the time, $t$ values for equivalent points. We can tell the red wave is one-quarter of a period ahead of the green one because the green wave matches the red one 2 seconds after.

Couldn't we say that the red wave is three-quarters of a period lagging behind that of the green one. To me, the graph seems to give no information about which wave is in front of the other. How do you define leading and lagging with wave terminology?

**Edit:** Here's my question. How do we define lagging and leading for waves on a displacement time graph? It seem that we can say the green wave is ahead by three-quarters a wavelength but also lagging behinf by one-quarter a wavelength. So do we consider both as correct?

Comment: For infinitely periodic waves, yes, you can say $\frac34$ lagging too. But the terminology is only well-defined if you stay within $(-\frac\pi2,+\frac\pi2]$, and then there is a unique answer to leading vs lagging. Of course, if you have a non-periodic wave, then the answer is unique in $\mathbb R$. We take the convention above for periodic waves because when used to analyse circuitry, it will agree between periodic and non-periodic.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to understand, if you set some reference. Imagine a phasor,
$$z=Ae^{i\omega{t}+\phi}$$
represent a complex number. It behaves like particles revolving in a circle at same distance but changing coordinates with time. Its sine component represents the oscillation when graphed with time.

At $t=0$, $\phi$ is the angle it forms with the positive real axis.
This tell us that our reference is nothing but the positive real axis.
Like any other complex number.
Phase$\in$$\;(-\pi,\pi]$ for it to have unique principle solution.
So,Instead of taking $$\phi=\frac{3\pi}{2}$$
It is taken as
$$\phi=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
A perfect sinosoid represent that at t=0, $\phi$ is also zero.
So, in this case green wave lags by $\frac{\pi}{2}$.